# JSONArray is not building properly

Tags: java

```
JSONArray topologyInfo = new JSONArray();
String[] ids = {"1","2","3"};
JSONObject topoInfo = readTaskLog(); //returns an object like {Name:"Stack"}
if (topoInfo != null) {
    for (String id : ids) {
        JSONObject tempobj=topoInfo;
        tempobj.put("id", id));
        topologyInfo.put(tempobj);
    }
}
```

I need to get 3 JSONObjects with name as Stack and id as 1,2 &3. In my JSONArray the 3 objects are with `"id" 3`
My final result should be like

```
[{
    "Name": "Stack",
    "id": "1"
},
{
    "Name": "Stack",
    "id": "2"
},
{
    "Name": "Stack",
    "id": "3"
}]
```

But I'm getting as

```
[{
    "Name": "Stack",
    "id": "3"
},
{
    "Name": "Stack",
    "id": "3"
},
{
    "Name": "Stack",
    "id": "3"
}]
```

Comment: I'd try `topologyInfo.add(tempobj);` and create new `JSONObject` instances in the loop.

Comment: How can we use add for JSONArray?

Comment: Adding a JSONObject to a JSONArray does NOT clone it, but you are writing the **same** object multiple times and replace the `id` in each loop step on this very object reference.

Comment: any working example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that you are reusing the same JSONObject in each iteration of the for loop so you are overriding the "id" value.

Try cloning the object instead...

```
JSONArray topologyInfo = new JSONArray();
String[] ids = {"1","2","3"};
JSONObject topoInfo = readTaskLog(); //returns an object like {Name:"Stack"}
if (topoInfo != null) {
    for (String id : ids) {
        JSONObject tempobj=new JSONObject(topoInfo.toString());
        tempobj.put("id", id));
        topologyInfo.put(tempobj);
    }
}
```

Comment: JSONObject.getNames(topoInfo) --> throwing an error here

Comment: an alternative would be to use JSONObject tempobj = new JSONObject(topoInfo.toString()); but this may be less performant

Comment: You can also create a JSONObject from scratch and use JSONObject#element to insert the 'id' and 'name' key/value pairs.

Comment: @PraveenMandadi if you are happy with this answer please accept it

Answer (score 1):

You're overriding the same property `'id'` every iteration.
`JSONObject#put` does refer to the `Map` interface.

That's because with:

```
JSONObject tempobj = topoInfo;
```

you're not dealing with a new `JSONObject`, but you're simply copying it's reference.